# How to style elements in foreach loop in specific pattern using php in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, loops

Please have a look at this image [image]

As you can see i have some posts fetching from the database. I want to give different style to posts in above pattern.

I have managed to give a different style to the first post using blade's `$loop iteration`. by the way i am using laravel 5. I want to give the same style to `post3` `post 4` `post 7` `post 8` and follow this pattern.
How can i achieve this using php?

Comment: You just use the key when looping. The first one will have some special stylings. All other will have different stylings for odd and even elements of array.

Comment: This is not odd even pattern. Please see the image)

Comment: ok, so the 10th element will be like the first?

Comment: No. only first element is full width and remaining all elements are above mentioned pattern

Comment: ok got it. so after first, there are blocks of 4 elements?

Comment: As shown in image first iterated element will be full width so i will add full width css style if it is first iteration. Then other iterations will have styles in above mentioned(see image) pattern .P.S. Only first element is full width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176593/discussion-between-truecode-and-naneri).

Comment: have u considered css as a styling option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this in your `foreach` directive:

```
@foreach ($blocks as $index => $block)
    @if ($index == 0)
        @include('full')
    @elseif ($index % 4 < 2)
        @include('gray')
    @else
        @include('blue')
    @endif
@endforeach
```

So basically, it will take the modulo of the index, and check if it's lower than 1. Which will give the following gray squares:

```
1, 4, 5, 8
```

And since it's the index (zero base), it will show the following blocks in gray:

```
2, 5, 6, 9
```

Then the other blocks will be in blue.

---

#### Example

```
$range = range(1, 9);

foreach ($range as $index => $block) {
    echo sprintf('Post %s: ', $index + 1);

    if ($index == 0) {
        echo 'full';
    } elseif ($index % 4 < 2) {
        echo 'gray';
    } else {
        echo 'blue';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

#### Result

```
Post 1: full
Post 2: gray
Post 3: blue
Post 4: blue
Post 5: gray
Post 6: gray
Post 7: blue
Post 8: blue
Post 9: gray
```